# Cannot pipe into another directory with bash?

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to use awk to reduce many columns of data into individual single columns of data, from INPUT dir, to OUTPUT.  However, using the attached code below, I get the following error: "OUTPUT/: Is a directory"

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=/INPUT/*
OUTPUT=/OUTPUT
for f in $FILES
do
    awk '{ print $3 }' $f > $OUTPUT/$f_1c
done
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can, only that you have to indicate the `$f` within brackets, not to have it considered as the variable `f_1c`:

```
awk '{ print $3 }' $f > $OUTPUT/${f}_1c
                                ^^^^
```

As you said in comments:

> However this adds the entire path to the filename in ${f}_1c, and bash
>   gives an error

then we have to get just the file name. This can be done with `basename`:

```
file_name=$(basename "$f")
awk '{ print $3 }' $f > $OUTPUT/${file_name}_1c
```

All together:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=/INPUT/*
OUTPUT=/OUTPUT
for f in $FILES
do
    file_name=$(basename "$f")
    awk '{ print $3 }' $f > $OUTPUT/${file_name}_1c
done
```

Comment: something something quote side

Comment: I see.  However this adds the entire path to the filename in ${f}_1c, and bash gives an error:
-bash: /OUTPUT//INPUT/mubunching-100302.0250.001_1c: No such file or directory

Comment: @StarStrides then you should use `file_name=$(basename "$f")` and then `awk '{ print $3 }' $f > $OUTPUT/${file_name}_1c`